# Does BigQuery encrypt data on disk?

Tags: encryption, google-bigquery

I have tried finding the answer to this but have only found anecdotal references. Does Google encrypt the data that is stored on BigQuery? If so, what encryption mechanisms are used?

Comment: I think the logical follow-on question to this is "where is the key stored?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All new data being added to BigQuery tables are encrypted using strong, industry-standard encryption methods. All old data will be encrypted over time, but currently with no specific timeline. If you'd like more detail on security across the Google Cloud Platform you might want to check out this blog post:

http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2014/08/googles-cloud-is-secure-but-you-dont.html

Comment: Is there an ETA for when this is expected to be in place across the board?

Comment: I'm the fairly-newly-minted Product Manager for BigQuery, and as a PM I have been conditioned to be physically incapable of communicating dates. :-) That said, I would estimate it's on the order of weeks/months as things currently stand. Sorry I can't be more precise.

Comment: No problem. Do note that all new data put in BigQuery is encrypted. All old data will be encrypted over time, but currently with no specific timeline.

Comment: Great! That is what is most important for me as I am just starting to roll out a service that is using BigQuery so all of the data will be new.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery is a part of Google's Cloud Platform Offering. As part of utilizing BigQuery you need to first load the data into it.

You can load Data 2 ways.

Load jobs support two data sources:

1. Objects in Google Cloud Storage
2. Data sent with the job or streaming insert

Data sourced from Google Cloud Storage is always encrypted as per the link below. Streaming data into BigQuery probably depends on how you stream it (I'm haven't found any absolute data on this point)

[Loading data into BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery)

[Description of Compute Engine Disks](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/compute-engine-disks-price-performance-and-persistence/)

Comment: I appreciate the response, but that info appears to only apply to when your data is actually stored on GCS. What I'm curious about is whether it's encrypted once it is already in BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, data stored in BigQuery is encrypted.

Google Cloud Platform encrypts data stored in BigQuery, without any action required from the user, using one or more encryption mechanisms.  Data stored in Google Cloud Platform is encrypted at the storage level using either AES256 or AES128.

There are more details in this whitepaper:
https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption-at-rest/